# How can I use threads to run this code simultaneously in rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a rust program that creates temporary email addresses using the [mail.tm API](https://api.mail.tm), and I want to use threads to create emails simultaneously, to increase the speed. However, what I have tried, only results in printing "Getting email.." x amount of times, and exiting. I am unsure what to do about this. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

```rust
use json;
use rand::distributions::Alphanumeric;
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};
use reqwest;
use reqwest::header::{HeaderMap, HeaderValue, ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE};
use std::{collections::HashMap, io, iter, vec::Vec};
use std::thread;

fn gen_address() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let address: String = iter::repeat(())
        .map(|()| rng.sample(Alphanumeric))
        .map(char::from)
        .take(10)
        .collect();

    let password: String = iter::repeat(())
        .map(|()| rng.sample(Alphanumeric))
        .map(char::from)
        .take(5)
        .collect();
    let body = reqwest::blocking::get("https://api.mail.tm/domains")
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .unwrap();
    let domains = json::parse(&body).expect("Failed to parse domain json.");

    let domain = domains["hydra:member"][0]["domain"].to_string();
    let email = format!("{}@{}", &address, &domain);
    vec![email, password]
}

fn gen_email() -> Vec<String> {
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let address_info = gen_address();
    let address = &address_info[0];
    let password = &address_info[1];

    let mut data = HashMap::new();
    data.insert("address", &address);
    data.insert("password", &password);

    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert(ACCEPT, HeaderValue::from_static("application/ld+json"));
    headers.insert(
        CONTENT_TYPE,
        HeaderValue::from_static("application/ld+json"),
    );

    let res = client
        .post("https://api.mail.tm/accounts")
        .headers(headers)
        .json(&data)
        .send()
        .unwrap();

    vec![
        res.status().to_string(),
        address.to_string(),
        password.to_string(),
    ]
}

fn main() {
    fn get_amount() -> i32 {
        let mut amount = String::new();

        loop {
            println!("How many emails do you want?");
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut amount)
                .expect("Failed to read line.");

            let _amount: i32 = match amount.trim().parse() {
                Ok(num) => return num,
                Err(_) => {
                    println!("Please enter a number.");
                    continue;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    let amount = get_amount();
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {

        for _gen in 0..amount {
            let handle = thread::spawn(|| {

                println!("Getting email...");
                let maildata = gen_email();
                println!(
                    "Status: {}, Address: {}, Password: {}",
                    maildata[0], maildata[1], maildata[2]);
            });
        }
    });
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do something with the thread handles from threads you spawn from within the outer thread? Maybe put the handles in a vector and then iteratively join them after the loop completes.

Comment: @Todd could you give me an example of what you are describing? No, I don't believe I need to do anything with the handles, other than use one to make sure that the program does not exit prematurely.

Comment: I believe that your thread that spawns new threads is going to exit early unless it joins its own threads.

Comment: How are you doing on this calvary? Were you able to get it working? I updated the [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b8ad29b76452b37aa040aa3c212e3231) - the server was killing the process because I put too long of a sleep in the child threads. I reduced their sleep to 1 second and it still demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: @Todd Sorry for the very late, I went to sleep, it works fine for me, heres a pastebin with the code I'm using. (I added .5 second sleep so I don't get 429 errors.) https://pastebin.com/r3Ak50nA

Comment: Looks good =) I'm glad you were able to get it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rust Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba3456a10184dcbd0843d5bc9b53e1ae)

I see a number of sub-threads being spawned from an outer thread. I think you might want to keep those handles and join them. Unless you join those sub threads the outer thread will exit early. I set up a Rust Playground to demonstrate ^^.

In the playground example, first run the code as-is and note the output of the code - the function it's running is `not_joining_subthreads()`. Note that it terminates rather abruptly. Then modify the code to call `joining_subthreads()`. You should then see the subthreads printing out their stdout messages.

```rust
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut handles = vec![];
        for _gen in 0..amount {
            let handle = thread::spawn(|| {

                println!("Getting email...");
                let maildata = gen_email();
                println!(
                    "Status: {}, Address: {}, Password: {}",
                    maildata[0], maildata[1], maildata[2]);
            });
            handles.push(handle);
        }
        handles.into_iter().for_each(|h| h.join().unwrap());
    });
    handle.join().unwrap();
```

Comment: I think something might need to be changed here, when running `cargo check` on this code, I get the error:  ```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*handle` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\main.rs:98:42
   |
98 |         handles.iter().for_each(|handle| handle.join().unwrap());
   |                                          ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*handle` has type `JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Hold on, I'll set up a rust playground with an example so we can verify the changes @cavalry1223. BTW, I updated the example to clone it's handles before joining them.. not 100% sure if that's what it needs, but you can try it while I"m setting up a running example.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I'll test it.
Edit:
Results:
2 Errors:
``the trait bound `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>: std::clone::Clone` is not satisfied``
and
``the method `for_each` exists for struct `std::iter::Cloned<std::slice::Iter<'_, std::thread::JoinHandle<()>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied``

Comment: Yeah.. my bad. The fix is to call `.into_iter()` on the vector holding the handles - remember that one ;-) you might hit that same error a few times. @cavalry1223

Comment: Like this? `` handles.into_iter().cloned().for_each(|h| h.join().unwrap());``
That gives me the errors:
``type mismatch resolving `<std::vec::IntoIter<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == &_```
``the method `for_each` exists for struct `std::iter::Cloned<std::vec::IntoIter<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
``

Edit: just needed to remove `.cloned`

Comment: Like I have it in the code ^^^ - you want to remove the `.cloned()` @cavalry1223